# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'name' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `products` (`featured_image`

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-livewire, heidisql

**SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'name' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `products` (`featured_image`, `product_attributes`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (7wtDzLjyBAIIGzQBSXVBwKqnuUPmh1OGLVpxLd2H.png, null, 2021-03-09 02:11:00, 2021-03-09 02:11:00))**

Any solution to my facing problem? Whenever I create only the validated part everything is fine. But, on adding "Product::create(['featured_image' => $this->featuredImage->hashName()]); return with above error.

## My Products Table

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->mediumText('description');
            $table->float('price');
            $table->string('featured_image')->nullable();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('shop_id')->nullable();
            $table->foreign('shop_id')->references('id')->on('shops')->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

## Datatable.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use App\Product;
use Livewire\Component;
use Livewire\WithPagination;
use Livewire\WithFileUploads;

class Datatable extends Component
{
    use WithFileUploads;
    use WithPagination;

    protected $products;

    public $featuredImage;

    public $sortBy = 'created_at';
    public $sortDirection = 'desc';
    public $search = '';
    public $perPage = 10;


    public $editModal = false;
    public $deleteModal = false;

    public $editingProduct;
    public $deletingProductId;


    public function render()
    {
        $this->fetchProducts();

        return view('livewire.datatable',[
            'items' => $this->products
        ]);
    }

    protected function fetchProducts()
    {
        $products = Product::search($this->search)
            ->orderBy($this->sortBy, $this->sortDirection)
            ->paginate($this->perPage);

        $this->products = $products;
    }

    public function updatingSearch()
    {
        $this->resetPage();
    }

    public function sortBy($field)
    {
        if ($this->sortDirection == 'asc') {
            $this->sortDirection = 'desc';
        } else {
            $this->sortDirection = 'asc';
        }

        return $this->sortBy = $field;
    }

    public function editProduct($product)
    {
        $this->editingProduct = $product;
        $this->editModal = true;
    }

    public function createProduct()
    {
        $this->reset();
        $this->editModal = true;
    }

    public function saveProduct()
    {
        $validated = $this->validate([
            'editingProduct.name' => 'required|min:3|max:20',
            'editingProduct.price' => 'required|min:1',
            'editingProduct.description' => 'required|min:5|max:30',
            'featuredImage' => 'required|image|max:1024|mimes:jpg,png,jpeg'
        ]);

        if(!empty($this->featuredImage)) {
            $this->featuredImage->store('public/photos');
        }

        if(!empty($this->editingProduct['id'])) {

            $product = Product::find($this->editingProduct['id']);
            $product->update($validated['editingProduct']);

        }else {
            Product::create($validated['editingProduct']);
            Product::create([
                'featured_image' => $this->featuredImage->hashName()
            ]);
        }

        $this->fetchProducts();

        $this->closeModal();
    }

    public function closeModal()
    {
        $this->editModal= $this->deleteModal = false;
    }

    public function confirmDelete($productId)
    {
        $this->deleteModal = true;
        $this->deletingProductId = $productId;
    }

    public function deleteProduct()
    {
        if(!empty($this->deletingProductId)) {
            Product::destroy($this->deletingProductId);
        }

        $this->deletingProductId = null;
        $this->fetchProducts();
        $this->closeModal();
    }
}
```

## datatable.blade.php

```
<div class="field">
    <label class="label">Name</label>
    <div class="control">
      <input wire:model.lazy="editingProduct.name" {{-- value="{{$editingProduct['name'] ?? null}}"
       --}} class="input" type="text" placeholder="Text input">

         @error('editingProduct.name')
         <p class="help is-danger">{{$message}}</p>
         @enderror
     </div>
</div>

                    <div class="field">
                        <label class="label">Description</label>
                        <div class="control">
                            <textarea class="textarea"placeholder="Textarea"
                                wire:model.lazy="editingProduct.description"></textarea>

                            @error('editingProduct.description')
                            <p class="help is-danger">{{$message}}</p>
                            @enderror
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

When I add ->nullable method to the field, there is no error but the data in table is null.

Comment: can you check your Products model? name should be fillable

Comment: @PendejoTrax Yes everything is fine in the fillable but still throwing this error.

Answer (score 3):

Without trying to dumpster-dive into your code ... SQL is throwing this error because you are attempting to insert a row into some table without specifying a value for *all* of the fields which do not have a prescribed default value in the schema.

Answer (score 0):

try putting this line

```
protected $guarded = [];
```

in your datatable.php file inside the datatable class

Comment: Please provide a detailed explanation to your answer, in order for the next user to understand your answer better.